# How to pass JSON values into Struct Ruby object?

Tags: ruby

Given a JSON object

```
{"a": 1, "b":2}
```

and a value object that is derived from a struct:

```
class A < Stuct.new(:a, :b)
end
```

How would I make an instance of A that has the values from the JSON?

I am trying:

```
 a = A.new(JSON.parse({a:1,b:2}.to_json).values)
 => #<struct A a=[1, 2], b=nil>
```

But I would expect a->1, and b->2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using:

```
a = A.new(*JSON[json].values)
a.class # => A < #<Class:0x00000102955828>
```

The problem is that `values` returns an array, but you need the individual elements of the array. Using `*` "splats" the array back into its components, which makes Struct happy when you pass the values to `new`.

---

EDIT:

> This will fail if the ordering of the JSON and the Struct do not match!

This forces the order of the values.

```
a = A.new(*JSON[json].values_at('a', 'b'))
{
    :a => 1,
    :b => 2
}
a.class # => A < #<Class:0x00000102955828>
```

JSON preserves the hash insertion order, as does Ruby, so, JSON rendered and parsed by Ruby will be correct. JSON rendered by something that doesn't preserve the order could be a problem, but `values_at` fixes the problem.

Note that JSON converts symbols to strings, so the keys passed to `values_at` have to be strings, not symbols.

Comment: This will fail if the ordering of the JSON and the Struct do not match!

Comment: It will, but JSON preserves ordering, as do Ruby hashes. So, if the JSON is generated by Ruby, then received by Ruby, the order should be intact. But there's a simple workaround I'll add.

Comment: If, yes. But the JSON can just as well come from the web, and then we've introduced a really hard to find bug!

Comment: It's a simple fix. See the code. It should never introduce a hard-to-find bug if you program defensively. Knowing where your data comes from is part of that. If you don't control the data, then you force it to the form you need prior to trying to process it.

Comment: thanks, in fact, I needed the values_at trick, since I am having some nested value objects from a Struct

Comment: Once upon a time, in Perl and Ruby, hashes didn't maintain their insertion order, so we had to extract the values in a known order. That's how we did it in my day. :-)

Answer (score 3):

If it does not have to be a predefined struct, this will work

```
a = Struct.new(*json.keys).new(*json.values)
```

Comment: `Struct.new(* ({'a' => 1}.keys) )` causes: `NameError: identifier a needs to be constant`. Seems that you can't pass strings as the member names. You could use `json.keys.map(&:to_sym)`, but if your ruby is < 2.2, this could cause a DOS because symbols aren't GC'd.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `splat` operator to pass the array values as arguments to the new function.

```
a = A.new(*{a:1,b:2}.values)
```